# How to filter out column duplicates when multiple selected (SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am trying to get all list names and a condition whether a specific item is contained in any of those lists.

Example data:

```
| item | name | 
+------+------+
| 1    | A    |
| 2    | A    |
| 3    | B    | 
| 4    | C    |
```

Current output:

```
| isFavorited | name | 
+-------------+------+
| N           | A    |
| Y           | A    |
| N           | B    | 
| N           | C    |
```

Expected output:

```
| isFavorited | name | 
+-------------+------+
| Y           | A    |
| N           | B    | 
| N           | C    |
```

Query:

```
declare @idItem nvarchar(50) = 'A'    

select distinct
    'isFavorited' = case when item = @idItem then 'Y' else 'N' end,
    'nameList'    = name
from 
    favorites
group by 
    name
```

How can I get a list of all distinct list names flagged for when an item is contained in that list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can filter duplicates of `isFavorited` by using the `max()` function.

```
declare @idItem nvarchar(50) = 'A'    

select distinct
  'isFavorited' = max(case when item = @idItem then 'Y' else 'N' end),
  'nameList'    = name
from 
  favorites
group by 
  nameList
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use self join and check if we have matching name with different item numbers.

```
with cte as (

select  1 as Item, 'A' as Name union all 
select  2 as Item, 'A' as Name union all 
select  3 as Item, 'B' as Name union all  
select  4 as Item, 'C' as Name) 

select c.name, case when c1.name is not null then 'Y' Else 'N' End IsFavorited  from cte c   
left join cte c1 on c1.Name = c.name  and c.Item != c1.Item   
group by c.name , case when c1.name is not null then 'Y' Else 'N' End
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the problem correct, then try this:

```
with cte1(name, cnt) as
(
select name, count(*) as cnt
from favorites
group by name
)
select name,
    case when cnt = 1 then 'N' else 'Y' end as IsFavorited
from cte1
```

OR alternatively:

```
select distinct name,
    case when name = 'A' then 'Y' else 'N' end IsFavorited
from favorites
```